# Does WatchKit support html? is there is controller like UIWebview?

Tags: uiwebview, html, watchkit

Does WatchKit  support html? is there is controller like UIWebview ?.

My client want to show webpage in a Apple Watch. is this possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `UIWebView` in `WatchKit` (neither `WatchOS 1` nor `WatchOS 2`).

However, it's fully possible to work around this:

You can load the `HTML`, pick out the relevant content, and display that in for example a `Label`. This is however not a smart solution, as the website owners can change its layout and render your app useless until you update it.

My suggestion is to send a `GET`-request to the server and receive the relevant data in `JSON`-format if they have an `API`. If they don't, you can use a service such as **Kimono** to convert the website into an `API`.

Or you could set up your own server which works as the `API`. You simply send a request to it, it queries the website/ loads the `HTML`, and returns the relevant content to your app.

In any case, the solution is to get the relevant content from the website and display that using labels and image views.

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering if there is a better solution after 3 years.
Is there a way to get data from website to your Apple watch?

Comment: @Alexandr watchOS 5 brought with it some changes, although I'm not exactly sure if it'll suit your needs. In any case you can learn more by watching this video from WWDC https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/239

Answer (score 4):

Seems like WatchOS5 has added limited support for WebKit:

- [How to use WebKit on watchOS 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50699459/26510)
- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/239

Answer (score 2):

There is no webView in watchKit ,But i managed to convert HTML to formatted String

```
func convertHTMLToFormattedText ( htmlText : String , myLabel : WKInterfaceLabel) {

    let attributeText: NSAttributedString?

    if let htmlData = htmlText.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding) {

        do {

            attributeText  =  try   NSAttributedString(data: htmlData , options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
            myLabel.setAttributedText(attributeText)

        }catch let e as NSError {
            print("Couldn't translate \(htmlText): \(e.localizedDescription) ")
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. There isn't anything like `UIWebView` in WatchKit.