# Cordova / Jquery Mobile & Apple Watch Development

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, apple-watch, phonegap

I currently create Iphone apps using cordova and JqueryMobile

Apple Watch 1 & 2 versions require the watch to pair the watch with the users iphone.

Does anyone know if thew apple watch 3 still required the watch to pair to an iphone or can the watch run apps loaded directly on the watch without requiring being paired to an iphone now that the Apple Watch has Celular

Just wondering if i can use the same platforms and code to develop an apple Watch compatible version of my app.

Looking Forward to your replies

Answer (score 0):

Cordova does not support the Apple-Watch as a platform and it will probably never be supported because app extensions (like a Watch-Extension, Today-Extension, iMessage-Extension, ...) are a native thing. [`WatchKit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit) (which is used for creating Watch-Apps) does not offer a possibility to integrate a webview (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839510/does-watchkit-support-html-is-there-is-controller-like-uiwebview) post), which is why cordova will not work at all.

But that does not mean you cant create a Watch-Extension for your cordova-app (you will have to implement your extension using Swift/Obj-C though). Have a look at this great plugin: [cordova-plugin-apple-watch](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch)

To your other question regarding the Apple-Watch 3: I *think* the development process will stay the same, Watch-Apps will still be extensions of a host app which has to be installed on the paired iPhone. Otherwise it must be possible to publish a watch-app as a standalone app in the App-Store - and I have never heard anything about that Apple plans to do so.

Comment: thanks for your detailed response shame i only code using cordova and jquery mobile without any Object-C skill set

hopefully in future ow that applewatch i celular it may open opportunity for dedicated standalone  apps to run on the watch without needing iphone connectivity

Comment: We'll see! If my answer solved your question then please accept it. :-)