# How to use webview or similar control in Watch OS?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-4

Example app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/watchup-for-whatsapp/id1320596975

I think this app might load whatsapp webview and parse responses from web and showing in whatsapp app, so any way to make webview or similar control that work in watch app?

EDIT: Can we load webview in iOS app in background and send parsed response to Appel Watch app? is it possible? I don't want to show webview in iPhone app, I just want parsed response and to show it in watch app in tableview app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does WatchKit support html? is there is controller like UIWebview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839510/does-watchkit-support-html-is-there-is-controller-like-uiwebview)

Comment: @arash Can we load webview in iOS app in background and send parsed response to Apple Watch app? is it possible? I don't want to show webview in iPhone app, I just want parsed response and to show it in watch app in tableview app.

Comment: @ScorpianAlive ddi you read Arash comment?