# How to use WebKit on watchOS 5?

Tags: watchos

At yesterday's WWDC, Apple have announced WebKit support in watchOS 5. I have downloaded Xcode 10 but can't find any reference to that in the Interface Builder or in the Frameworks and Libraries tab. Although Apple's `WebKit` website has been unable for access yesterday, they haven't added documentation about watchOS yet.

How can I make use of WebKit and WatchKit?

Answer (score 0):

Quite a useful video from this years WWDC about this here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/239

Basically, it seems like it will use a 320px viewport and then scale it down to the width of the Apple Watch screen which sounds very logical.

As expected there is a new meta tag to allow you to overcome that behavior and put custom styles in.

Quite well thought out in my opinion even though i'm not fully expecting the experience to be super user friendly.

Comment: Hey, sorry if I didn't make this clear enough in my question but I was asking from a watchOS programmer standpoint, not a web developer one haha

Comment: @user2875404 Oh i'm so sorry. I misread your post. Apologies!

Comment: Note that the linked video mentions ‘WebKit in messages and mail’.  I wonder if this is why the WebKit docs aren’t updated, maybe it’s only a private framework in watchOS 5?

Comment: no worries my friend, it was my fault not to make my post more clear, will edit now
@Cobra could well be possible but then I wouldn't have called it "WebKit" but rather "Safari support" or something along the lines :/ hate having to give up fresh hopes

Comment: Yeah, they said 'webkit is coming to watchOS', but it certainly isn't documented for developers yet.  Given the demo's just used links in mail/messages, this makes me think they meant 'webkit is available for rendering', but not for third party apps, sadly.

Comment: @Cobra Hi, where does it say that they will make WebKit available on watchOS?

Comment: Can you get to the developer video link?  It should be searchable in the transcript, I would think.

Comment: The author of that post didnt even watch the video...